# Как конвертировать домен из unicode в punycode?

Tags: php

Как на php переконвертировать домен в url из unicode в punycode (например, "`президент.рф`" в "`xn--d1abbgf6aiiy.xn--p1ai`")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте пакет [Net_IDNA2](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_IDNA2/)