# Алгоритм работы Punycode

Tags: utf-8

Уже не знаю, где спросить, поэтому попробую здесь, может кто ответит.
Купил [скрипт конструктор сайтов](http://construktor.info), но он не поддерживает русские домены.
Спецификацию RFC 3492 я почитал, хотя с английским довольно недружен, но тем не менее. Класс для создания Idn доменов я нашел, но как работает так и не понял. Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: а в их саппорте пробовали спросить? как никто создатели должны это знать.

Comment: Они ответили что поддержка русских поддоменов будет позже, а мне надо сейчас.

Answer (score 2):

Википедия вполне прилично рассказывает, как преобразовать в [punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode)

Есть ещё вариант подсмотреть [псевдо-код](http://xn--e1afmkfd.xn--80akhbyknj4f/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Comment: К сожалению я не знаю языка Глагол, что по второй ссылке. Возможно http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode достаточно прилично, но с английским у меня проблема. Если Можете объяснить по русски, то буду признателен

Comment: @Арсен , может быть просто взять готовый класс для генерации доменных имен в punycode? Вот, пожалуйста, всё включено: http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/5845.html

Comment: У меня есть класс, я хочу узнать как работает алгоритм

Comment: Тогда читайте спецификацию: http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3492.txt

Comment: Описание работы алгоритма достойно отдельной статьи. Наверно именно поэтому описание стандарта весит весит 60 Кб, а алгоритм по нему около 90 Кб.
Вкратце:
— Берётся последовательность Unicode code points. 
— Из неё выписываются ASCII-символы (codepoints U+0021...U+007F) с сохранением оригинального порядка.
— Если остались не-ASCII символы, добавляется минус в качестве разделителя.
— Для каждого из оставшихся не-ASCII символов указывается его код и позиция, куда его нужно вставить, одним числом. Это число записывается в 36-ной системе. Как это число формируется - одним предложением не опишешь.

Comment: Я единственное, что могу посоветовать, это загнать хотя бы материал Википедии в translate.google.ru . Нет там проблем со сложной лексикой, поэтому будет понятно с любым автоматическим переводчиком.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам нужна реализация энкодера/декодера на php, то вот [здесь](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_IDNA2/) и [здесь](http://phlymail.com/en/downloads/idna-convert.html) готовые варианты.

Похожий вопрос уже был задан ранее: [Как конвертировать домен из unicode в punycode?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/7371/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%B8%D0%B7-unicode-%D0%B2-punycode)

Если же нужен сам алгоритм, то читайте спецификацию: [Punycode: A Bootstring encoding of Unicode](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3492.txt)

Answer (score 0):

Вот [здесь](www.rsdn.ru/forum/cpp/4045614.flat) то же самое написано.
Но это все равно не ответ на вопрос.
Кроме прочего стандарт описывает и алгоритм, только к сожалению насколько понял на С, и принцип работы и лицензию и благодарности и тд. Сам класс, весом 90 кб тоже имеет кучу проверок, комментариев и прочего, также имеет настройки и алгоритмы с этим связанные. Но основная суть кодирования описана в этой функции `_encode` размером в нескольких десяток строк, хотя я еще до конца с ней не разобрался, но и она наполовину, это то, что я уже разобрал, не сам способ кодирования. Но все на английском.

Comment: Разбирая класс http://phlymail.com/en/downloads/idna-convert.html в целом я застрял на конечном автомате, с которым познакомился только сегодня. Т.е. смысл кодировки сводится к тому, чтобы привести символы в их десятиричное представление. Убрать все не ascii символы, спереди добавить xn-- а в конце -. А дальше уже идет алгоритм конечного автомата, который кроется в функции   protected function _encode($decoded) и мне не очень понятен.

Comment: Соответственно вопрос в том как работает конечный автомат, соответственно, для данного случае интересует больше. Но любой ответ будет в помощь