# Как на PHP перевести домен .рф в латинскую версию?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Понадобилось функционально делать перевод домена в ёлки-с-доставкой.рф в такое xn-----8kciivmbgc2bd6adp4u.xn--p1ai

**Как это сделать на PHP?**

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.idn-to-utf8.php https://github.com/true/php-punycode

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/7371/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%b8%d0%b7-unicode-%d0%b2-punycode/7373#7373

Answer (score 2):

как посоветовал @Etki, следует использовать функцию [idn_to_ascii](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.idn-to-ascii.php) (обратное преобразование: [idn_to_utf8](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.idn-to-utf8.php)).

вполне вероятно, что речь идёт о сервере под управлением операционной системы *gnu/linux*. там надо установить пакет `php5-intl` (`php-idn` и т.п.), содержащий реализацию этих функций.

пример:

```
$ php -r "echo idn_to_ascii('домен.рф');"
xn--d1acufc.xn--p1ai

$ php -r "echo idn_to_utf8('xn--d1acufc.xn--p1ai');"
домен.рф
```

Answer (score 0):

Чаще всего советуют использовать сторонние классы.
Например есть [вот такой пример](http://artkiev.com/blog/php-punycode-convert.htm).

Comment: Еще лучше использовать библиотеку, подгружаемую через composer, как в моем комментарии.